# Prevent ActionResult from posting to a new page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

My project is very similar to [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) and I'm generating a pdf-document using PdfSharp.

In my view I'm using this:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Pdf", "GeneratePdf1", "Persons")%>
```

Calling this ActionResult:

```
    public ActionResult GeneratePdf1()
    {
        // Create a new PDF document
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

        // Create an empty page
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

        // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

        // Create a font
        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

        // Draw the text
        gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
        new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
        XStringFormats.Center);

        // Save the document...
        const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";
        document.Save(filename);
        Process.Start(filename);
        return View();
    }
```

A few questions/problems on this:

- I don't want the link to post. When you click the link it should just open the file, but I don't know what to return to prevent it from posting.
- I'd also like the "save/open" dialog to appear. Right now the pdf file is displayed directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to return a `FileResult` not an `ActionResult`. Also, I would save it to a `MemoryStream` and return the byte array, not use a file. Full solution below.

```
public FileResult GeneratePdf1()
{
    // Create a new PDF document
    PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
    document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

    // Create an empty page
    PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

    // Create a font
    XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

    // Draw the text
    gfx.DrawString("Hello, World!", font, XBrushes.Black,
    new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, page.Height),
    XStringFormats.Center);


    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    document.Save(stream, false);

    return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: I like to know why you suggest **Also, I would save it to a MemoryStream and return the byte array, not use a file**.

Comment: Because if you save it to a file, it could have the same name as another request, and you could get another user's file. If you are going to use a file, you need to name it uniquely for the request.

Comment: Ah okay, I missed the `document.Save(filename)` with a static filename. That indeed is very important. Thx for opening my eyes! This is worth a +1 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

you should replace these lines:

```
Process.Start(filename);
return View();
```

with

```
return File(filename, "application/pdf");
```

You may also have a third param with the downloaded filename, if it should be different to the action name.

```
return File(filename, "application/pdf", "myGeneratedPdf.pdf");
```

Also be sure the filename is unique per request or use a `MemoryStream` like it is suggested by Chris Kooken.

Btw: `Process.Start(filename)` will run the file on the server machine. that may work on your development machine, but on a live server the pdf will open on the server!!!

Comment: `No overload method for 'File' takes 1 arguments`

Comment: Yeah i missed the content type. corrected that some seconds ago.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `on a live server the pdf will open on the server`